# Finding the Point at Which a Function is a Maximum when the Derivative is a Transcendental Function

Tags: optimization

Take

$$
f\left(x\right)=-x\left( x\sqrt{4-x^2}-4\arccos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \right)\arccos\left(\frac{x^2+d^2-1}{2dx}\right)
$$

and try to find the point where $f$ is at a maximum, given $1< x<2$.

I've tried solving $f'\left( x \right)=0$ but the equation is (I think) transcendental in $x$. Mathematica can't solve this either.

If I want to find an approximation to this function (in the form of a second order polynomial) that is accurate at the maximum of $f$, how can I go about it?

Comment: I'm not sure what values of $d$ you're interested in, but running the code $$Manipulate[
 Plot[x ((4 - x^2)^{0.5} - 4 ArcCos[x/2]) ArcCos[(x^2 + d^2 - 1)/(
    2 x d)], {x, 0, 3}], {d, 0.000001, 10}]$$ in Mathematica suggests that the maximum is either $x$ arbitrarily close to its upper limit or when $f(x)=0$

Comment: the range of d is 2<d<3

Comment: OK, doesn't the maximum occur when $f(x)=0$ then?

Comment: The function clearly takes values greater than 0

Comment: You mean f'(x) = 0?